# Javascript: grouping array of objects by id

Tags: javascript

I have a problem which I seem have almost no clue to get the answer to.

I do not know what i am doing wrong.

**Code:**

```js
function groupBy(arr, cb) {
  var groups = {};
  arr.forEach(function(o) {
    var group = JSON.stringify(cb(o));
    groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
    groups[group].push(o);
  });
  return Object.keys(groups).map(function(group) {
    return groups[group];
  });

  var result = groupBy(arr, function(i) {
    return currentObject.branch.id;
  })
}

var list = [{
  id: "102",
  name: "Alice"
}, {
  id: "205",
  name: "Bob",
  title: "Dr."
}, {
  id: "592",
  name: "Clyde",
  age: 32
}];

console.log(groupBy(list, function(i) {
  return i.id;
}));
```

**What it should return:**

```
{
"102": [{id: "102", name: "Alice"}],
"205": [{id: "205", name: "Bob", title: "Dr."}],
"592": [{id: "592", name: "Clyde", age: 32}]
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?  If so, what are they and on what lines?

Comment: Do you realize that you're attempting to call `groupBy` *inside* of `groupBy`?

Comment: Why are you calling `groupBy` recursively?

Answer (score 4):

You need just to return `groups`, without stringify the object before.

```js
function groupBy(array, cb) {
    var groups = Object.create(null);
    array.forEach(function (o) {
        var key = cb(o);
        groups[key] = groups[key] || [];
        groups[key].push(o);
    });
    return groups;
}


var list = [{ id: "102", name: "Alice" }, { id: "205", name: "Bob", title: "Dr." }, { id: "592", name: "Clyde", age: 32 }];

console.log(groupBy(list, function (i) { return i.id; }));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What is **`.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }`** used for?

Comment: it spreads the console to 100 % hight, to read more of the result.

Comment: Oh that's clever Nina, injecting CSS for the snippet console. Claps for you! +1

Comment: That's a nice thought @NinaScholz.

Comment: it is not from me, but handy.